# PHP -grouping Json array structure to multidimensional array and json_decode not working

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, grouping

Can somebody lend me some help in this..Below are the data i new to group and subgroup them

```
{

    "id":"1",
    "ppmp_id":"43",
    "allot_class":"Expenditures",
    "fund_code":"50202010",
    "fund_desc":"50202010 Training ",
    "qty":"2",
    "unit_cost":"100000.00",
    "total_cost":"200000.00",
    "qty_jan":"2",
    "qty_feb":"1",
    "qty_mar":"1",
    "qty_apr":"1",
    "description":"Isoprophyl Alcohol Gardian "
},
{

    "id":"2",
    "ppmp_id":"43",
    "allot_class":"Expenditures",
    "fund_code":"50202010",
    "fund_desc":"50202010 Training ",
    "qty":"5","unit_cost":"50000.00",
    "total_cost":"100000.00",
    "qty_jan":"1",
    "qty_feb":"1",
    "qty_mar":"1",
    "qty_apr":"2",
    "description":"Rebisco Wafer Time Rich Cream"
},
{

    "id":"5",
    "ppmp_id":"43",
    "allot_class":"Maintenance,
    "fund_code":"45354354",
    "fund_desc":"Dev","qty":"1",
    "unit_cost":"45000.00",
    "total_cost":"45000.00",
    "qty_jan":"1",
    "qty_feb":"2",
    "qty_mar":"3",
    "qty_apr":"4",
    "description":"Radeon Vega GraphicsSocket"
},  
{

    "id":"6",
    "ppmp_id":"43",
    "allot_class":"Maintenance",
    "fund_code":"45354354",
    "fund_desc":"Dev",
    "qty":"2","unit_cost":"10000.00",
    "total_cost":"20000.00",
    "qty_jan":"1",
    "qty_feb":"2",
    "qty_mar":"4",
    "description":"Graphics EngineNVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050"
},
{   

    "id":"8",
    "ppmp_id":"43",
    "allot_class":"Other Optg.",
    "fund_code":"78677899",
    "fund_desc":"Supplies",
    "qty":"5","unit_cost":"12000.00",
    "total_cost":"60000.00",
    "qty_jan":"2",
    "qty_feb":"5",
    "qty_mar":"6",
    "qty_apr":"2",
    "description":"Core MemoryBoost Clock"
},
{

    "id":"9",
    "ppmp_id":"43",
    "allot_class":"Other Optg.",
    "fund_code":"78677899",
    "fund_desc":"Supplies",
    "qty":"1","unit_cost":"74998.00",
    "total_cost":"74998.00",
    "qty_jan":"3",
    "qty_feb":"5",
    "qty_mar":"5",
    "qty_apr":"1",
    "description":"Core USB Type"
},
```

and i find a hardtime in grouping and subgrouping them by this format

first it was group by allot_class and then subgroup by fund code and then sub_group again by description under the description was qty per month

allot_class

```
- fund_code
    - description
        -qty_jan
        -qty_feb
        -qty_mar
        -qty-apr
```

allot_class

```
- fund_code
    - description
        -qty_jan
        -qty_feb
        -qty_mar
        -qty-apr
```

I've tried this code but it says

Message:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

i've also tried it in sand box where it was working fine

```
    $command = "CALL sp_ppmp_items_get_all_per_ppmp(?);";

    $proc_db = $this->load->database('pgbhus_procurement', TRUE);
    $result = $proc_db->query($command, $data);
    $proc_db->close();
    if ($result) {
    $data_arr  = $result->result_array();

//the result here was as stated above 
    if (count($data_arr) > 0) {
    $new_array = json_decode($data_arr, true);
    $testarr = [];     
    foreach ($new_array as $key1=>$val1){
    foreach ($val1 as $key2=>$val2){            
    if($key2=='allot_class'){
    $num=$val2;
    if($val2!=$num)
    $testarr['allot_class '.$val2]=array();}
    if($key2=='fund_desc'){
    $testarr['allot_class '.$num]['fund_desc '.$val2][]=$val1;} }}
    return $testarr;
    } else {
    return "No data found"; } }
    return "Error has occured"; }
```

i want to accomplish this, it was the output as i execute in sandbox

Result

```
Array
(

    [allot_class Expenditures] => Array
        (
            [fund_desc 50202010 Training] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [ppmp_id] => 43
                            [allot_class] => Expenditures
                            [fund_code] => 50202010
                            [fund_desc] => 50202010 Training
                            [qty] => 2
                            [unit_cost] => 100000.00
                            [total_cost] => 200000.00
                            [qty_jan] => 2
                            [qty_feb] => 1
                            [qty_mar] => 1
                            [qty_apr] => 1
                            [description] => Isoprophyl Alcohol Gardian 
                        )

                )

            [fund_desc 50202010 Training ] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [ppmp_id] => 43
                            [allot_class] => Expenditures
                            [fund_code] => 50202010
                            [fund_desc] => 50202010 Training 
                            [qty] => 5
                            [unit_cost] => 50000.00
                            [total_cost] => 100000.00
                            [qty_jan] => 1
                            [qty_feb] => 1
                            [qty_mar] => 1
                            [qty_apr] => 2
                            [description] => Rebisco Wafer Time Rich Cream
                        )

                )

        )

    [allot_class Maintenance] => Array
        (
            [fund_desc Dev] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [ppmp_id] => 43
                            [allot_class] => Maintenance
                            [fund_code] => 45354354
                            [fund_desc] => Dev
                            [qty] => 1
                            [unit_cost] => 45000.00
                            [total_cost] => 45000.00
                            [qty_jan] => 1
                            [qty_feb] => 2
                            [qty_mar] => 3
                            [qty_apr] => 4
                            [description] => Radeon Vega GraphicsSocket
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 6
                            [ppmp_id] => 43
                            [allot_class] => Maintenance
                            [fund_code] => 45354354
                            [fund_desc] => Dev
                            [qty] => 2
                            [unit_cost] => 10000.00
                            [total_cost] => 20000.00
                            [qty_jan] => 1
                            [qty_feb] => 2
                            [qty_mar] => 4
                            [description] => Graphics EngineNVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050
                        )

                )

        )

    [allot_class Other Optg.] => Array
        (
            [fund_desc Supplies] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 8
                            [ppmp_id] => 43
                            [allot_class] => Other Optg.
                            [fund_code] => 78677899
                            [fund_desc] => Supplies
                            [qty] => 5
                            [unit_cost] => 12000.00
                            [total_cost] => 60000.00
                            [qty_jan] => 2
                            [qty_feb] => 5
                            [qty_mar] => 6
                            [qty_apr] => 2
                            [description] => Core MemoryBoost Clock
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 9
                            [ppmp_id] => 43
                            [allot_class] => Other Optg.
                            [fund_code] => 78677899
                            [fund_desc] => Supplies
                            [qty] => 1
                            [unit_cost] => 74998.00
                            [total_cost] => 74998.00
                            [qty_jan] => 3
                            [qty_feb] => 5
                            [qty_mar] => 5
                            [qty_apr] => 1
                            [description] => Core USB Type
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: I really need to group them by arrays datas will be use for front end and needed to be grouped like that since we use php on the backend and react&material-ui in the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

it seems $data_arr is an array, according to [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) of json_decode(), the first parameter must be a string.
i dont know what is the type of this array but the code must be like this

```
$new_array = json_decode($data_arr["index"], true);
```